# Is this phrase correct

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammar

I wrote on a snapchat:

> Just when I think stephen cant get any **more cringey**

But just after I sent it, it struck me that it might be wrong and could’ve been

> Just when I think stephen cant get any **cringer**

but im not sure

Answer (score -1):

Naturally I think I would say "cringier", but "more cringey" doesn't sound wrong either. It's hard to say, since it's not really an official English word.

Answer (score -1):

In [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cringey) we find:

> **cringey**
>
> variants: or less commonly **cringe-y** or **cringy**

In [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cringey) we find:

> **cringey**
>
> adjective, also **cringy**

While in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cringy#English) we find:

> **cringy**
>   Alternative forms: **cringey**

However, only Wiktionary provides the 3 forms of the adjective:

> **cringy** (comparative **cringier** or **more cringy**, superlative **cringiest** or **most cringy**)

Conclusion: both **more cringey** and **cringer** are correct.

---

Other comments on your snapchat:

1. **cant** in this context must be spelled **can't**, otherwise you get the wrong meaning
2. The use of the present tense is unnatural. Unless you are in the middle of telling a story vividly, bringing the past to the present, you should use past tense:

> “just when I **thought** stephen **couldn't get** any more cringey”

No comment on spelling a person's name with the wrong letter case ;)

Comment: Anyone cares to explain the down-vote, please?

Answer (score -3):

Grammatically, you could have said "cringier" or "much cringy" and on only one occasion can you say "more cringey" which is when you apostrophize the phrase. It gives the addressee a solid impression that such manner of usage was intentional, though not grammatically correct but is understood.

Comment: This is incorrect. "more cringey" is perfectly acceptable, indeed I would pefer it to the also correct  "cringier"..  "much cringy" would not be correct in this form, and i'm not sure it could ever be correct.